# Need a little help cleaning up this code. Just want it to show a 2/2 reversal on the hourly scanning stocks with a price above $20

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Just want it to show a 2/2 reversal on the hourly scanning stocks with a price above $20 with volume over 1 million. Would like it to go off the 4 hour chart I'd like for it to scan the total stock market and crypto markets. Having trouble with my inputs.

```
//@version=5
strategy(title="2 2 Reversal Strategy", overlay=true)

// Define inputs
var float     minimumPrice= const int (title="Minimum Stock Price", type=const.int.float, defval=20.0, step=.1)
var int      minimumVolume = const int (title="Minimum Stock Volume (in millions)", type=const.integer, defval=1)

// Define conditions for the 2 2 reversal pattern
`var bool      bullishPattern = close[3] < open[3] and close[2] < open[2] and close[1] > high[3] and close > high[2]
var bool      bearishPattern = close[3] > open[3] and close[2] > open[2] and close[1] < low[3] and close < low[2]

// Define conditions for minimum stock price and volume
var bool     minimumPriceCondition = close > minimumPrice
var bool     minimumVolumeCondition = volume / 1000000 > minimumVolume
```

Comment: is that a ChatGPT code? It does not make any sense.